# Can I squash a merge commit with one of its predecessors?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rewrite-history

Let's say I start with a history like this:

```
A---B---C
 \
  \-D---E
```

Then, I merge the two branches, resolving some conflicts in the process:

```
A---B---C---F
 \         /
  \-D---E-/
```

But afterwards, I want to rewrite history to look something like this:

```
A---B---C---EF
 \         /
  \-D-----/
```

In other words, I want to move the changes from branch commit `E` into merge commit `F`.  As if I had made the changes in `E` while manually resolving conflicts from merging `D` into `C`.

(My practical reason is that `E` was merely a merge preparation commit, to make anticipated conflicts a little easier to resolve.  It doesn't have much value on its own, and I don't want it polluting the history.  I don't want to squash E into *its* predecessor, because its changes are logically separate.)

I tried:

```
git rebase -i --rebase-merges HEAD~10
```

But that gives me:

```
...
pick 1069500 ...
merge -C 44c0a69 ...

# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# ...
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
```

So it looks like a commit can be a merge commit, *or* `git rebase -i` can squash it into its predecessor, but not both.  And `git rebase` would [make me reapply my manual conflict resolutions](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---rebase-mergesrebase-cousinsno-rebase-cousins), anyway, which kinda stinks.

Is there another approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use `git commit-tree` to make a new merge commit with `F`'s snapshot and your chosen parents, then force your branch name to point there:

```
newcommit=$(git commit-tree -p HEAD^ -p HEAD^2^ HEAD^{tree} -F /tmp/msg)
```

where `/tmp/msg` contains the commit message you'd like to use.  Then use `git reset` to move the current branch / commit to `$newcommit`, after checking that this commit looks the way you'd like (`git log --graph --oneline $newcommit` for instance).

(This assumes a Unix-like shell, with shell variables set with `var=value`, `$(...)` to run a command, and so on.)

#### Long

Commits do not store changes.  They store snapshots.

This is true for merge commits as well: their snapshots are *snapshots*.  They hold full and complete copies of every file *in each file's merged form*.

So suppose you have:

```
A--B--C--F
 \      /
  D----E
```

(this is your original drawing, I just pushed the commits around a bit to a style I like better) and would like to have:

```
A--B--C--G
 \      /
  D----'
```

(I just used a whole new letter for merge `G` here, but this is the same as your `EF`).  The *snapshot* for merge commit `G` must exactly match the existing snapshot for merge commit `F`.  The first parent of merge commit `G` must be commit `C`—the same as the first parent of existing commit `F`—and the second parent must be commit `D`, skipping over commit `E`, but most importantly, the *snapshot* for `G` should be exactly the same as the snapshot you already made with merge commit `F`.

Now, you can easily produce *this* graph:

```
        ___
       /   \
A--B--C--F  G
 \      /  /
  D----E  /
   \_____/
```

from the graph you already have, by making new commit `G`.  The `git commit-tree` command does exactly that.

You must supply three things to `git commit-tree`:

- A set of parent hash IDs, or names that resolve to hash IDs.  You need the IDs of commits `C` and `D`, which you can spell using `HEAD^1` and `HEAD^2^1` respectively.  Each `1` can be omitted.  These are the `-p` arguments.
- The tree hash ID for the new commit.  Since `HEAD` is commit `F` and its tree is the one you want, `HEAD^{tree}` specifies that.
- A commit log message, with `-m` or `-F` or from stdin.

The commit-tree program writes out the new commit object and prints its hash ID, which we'd like to capture in a human-readable form using a shell variable.

Once this is done we just need to update the current branch name.  Since this branch is currently checked out, we will use `git reset`:

```
git reset $newcommit
```

We could `git reset --soft` to avoid changing the current index, or `git reset --hard` to change the index and work-tree, but if the current index and work-tree match the snapshot in existing merge commit `F`, the snapshot in merge `G` is exactly the same anyway so there's no real need for either flag.  The default `--mixed` reset will reset the index, leaving the work-tree undisturbed.  (If you've carefully staged stuff, though, you might want `--soft`.)

Commit `F` will continue to exist, but with no *name* that finds it, you won't see it—and eventually, once the reflog that keep it around expire, Git's garbage collector will toss out commits `F` and `E`.

Comment: Just to be sure, `F^{tree}` or `HEAD^{tree}` refers to the snapshot alone (just the files), while `F` refers to the whole commit (files, message, author, etc.), such that we should have `${newcommit}^{tree} == F^{tree}` after the `git commit-tree` command. Is this correct? You are a great explainer, thank you.

Comment: @leogama: yes, just so: the `^{<type>}` suffix tells the revision parsing code that after it locates the hash ID for whatever comes before the caret, it should then do whatever it takes to find a suitable hash ID for the given type. Some types don't convert—for instance, if the hash on the left of `^{tree}` is a blob hash, the `^{tree}` produces an error. But a commit always has exactly one tree so `F^{tree}` works every time when `F` is a commit.

Comment: Note that some (mostly "porcelain") Git commands do the equivalent magic for you, e.g., `git diff`, given a commit hash specifier, converts the commit hash to a tree hash to do the diff-ing. Other (mostly "plumbing") Git commands don't, so that you need some syntax or code to get the right kind of object.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
git checkout $( git commit-tree -p C -p D -m "some merge" F^{tree} )
```

You will end up in detached HEAD on a revision just like what you are requesting (check with git log or gitk, check the files).... if you like it:

```
git branch-f some-branch
git checkout some-branch
```